# How to export 'measures' data from sonarqube to excel?

Tags: excel, database, sonarqube

Is there a way to export the metrics from the 'measures' tab in sonarqube to excel without querying a database? I am currently using the embedded db for testing purposes on SonarQube 7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the footer of every page is a link to the on-board Web API docs. You can use the services listed there to pull this data. Specifically, you probably want `api/measures/component`. Note that the data will be returned in a JSON format, so you'll need to do some scrubbing to make it ready for Excel.

Comment: Thank you the reply. Unfortunately, the web api you mentioned only works for individual projects/components. If I wanted to get these measures on all the projects in the db, how would do this?

Comment: ... iterate over the projects?